# Shared and seamless gradient effect between two objects? [EEVEE]

Tags: node-editor, objects, eevee-render-engine

I've been sitting on getting a flame gradient achieved since I didn't know how to get it to be seamless between two objects. I used very basic mapping, but of course it looks rudimentary:

[image: The gradient looks scuffed]

And here's the screens of both the node sets for the head and the flame:

[image: Head Nodes]

[image: Flame Nodes]

The flame is a flat plane that uses and image texture, where as the head relies on its own mesh, so I hope it doesn't complicate things.

How can I get a seamless 'universal' texture that will look consistent between both objects?

Here's a mockup to show what I'm aiming at (also ignore the fact there isn't a flame outline, it doesn't matter)

[image: Mockup of seamless gradient]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually now figured it out after coming back with a fresh mind.

I used texture coordinates from the head for both my image object and the head itself in the end, combined with a camera node.

Image node setup:
[image: Image setup]

Head node setup:
[image: Head setup]

I specifically made the axis Y to get a consistent vertical look, and **made both the image object and head share the same origin.**

I'm sure that's also a deciding factor to get what I ended up with.

Hope this helps anyone!

Answer (score 3):

If you use the "Object" output from the "Texture Coordinates" node on both shaders, and then set the origin of both objects to the same location, the seam should disappear.

Example :

[image]

[image]

Also :

[image]